# Как хостить 2 разные игры на свой и гостевой ПК?

Tags: windows

Доброго времени суток.
Суть вопроса такая: есть мощный ПК (далее ПК-1), на котором надо запустить игру, допустим CS:GO для себя, т.е. на ПК-1 и спокойно сидеть себе играть в CS:GO, а так же запустить игру, например, CS 1.6. для гостевого ПК (далее ПК-2), чтобы с ПК-2 можно было спокойно бегать/прыгать/стрелять, Nvidia Gamestream co-op не подходит по ряду причин: 1) ПК-2 имеет офисную затычку в виде GT-440; 2) оба ПК находятся в локальной сети;
Чем можно такое провернуть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Серверная ОСь(патч на пользовательскую ОСь для нескольких одновременных сеансов) + RDP с пробросом всего необходимого(мышь клава джойстик звук).

Comment: На стандартную 10ку слишком затратно выйдет?

Comment: Затратно в чем? стандартная 10ка - не серверная. Патч - вариант для пиратов =)

Comment: О каком именно патче идет речь?
Если можно, то лучше ссылку :)

Comment: Не думаю что тут можно такие ссылки, речь о патче RDP Wrapper, найти его не проблема

Comment: Да, спасибо, проблему решил :)